# Which has better performace, fewer DB queries or less code?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am developing a MEAN webapp. I've been two days thinking about which of the following two approaches have better performance.

I currently have a MongoDB database with:

- Device schema: 1000 devices (documents).
- Rental schema: 1700 rentals(documents. Nearly 2 rental average per device).
- Reading schema : 1.000.000 readings(documents. 1000 readings aprox. per device).

In the dashboard, I need to get all the client active rentals (50-100 rental m.ax per client). then, for each rental I need to get its device by deviceId field for each device its last reading document by deviceId too.

### OPTION1:

```
//1. I get the client rentals
    Rental.find({
        start_date: {
            "$lte": new Date()
        },
        end_date: {
            "$gte": new Date()
        },
        clientId : ObjectId(req.params.clientId)
    }, 'deviceId', function(err, Rentals)      {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err)
        } else {

            //2. I create an array with the required deviceIds
            var finalDevices = Rentals.map(function (obj) {
              return obj.deviceId;
            });

            //3. In paralel 
            Async.parallel([
                function(callback) {

                        //3.1 Get devices by the array of deviceIs (only one BD query)
                        Device.find({
                            "_id": { "$in": finalDevices } 
                        },
                        function(err, devices) {
                            if (err) {
                                callback(err, null);
                            } else {
                                callback(null, devices)
                            }
                        }); 

                },
                function(callback) {

                        //3.1 Get last reading for each device (only one BD query)
                        Reading.aggregate([
                            { $match: { "deviceId": { "$in": deviceIds}  } },
                            {
                                $group: {
                                    deviceId: "$deviceId",
                                    maxCreatedAt: { $max: "$createdAt" }
                                }
                            }
                        ],function(err, readings) {
                            if (err) {
                                callback(err, null);
                            } else {
                                callback(null, readings)
                            }
                        })
                }
            ],
            // optional callback
            function(err, results) {
                // create and object matching Rentals array, devices array and readings array by deviceId. Pending. I suppose I'll need to iterate through each array which will be bad performing...
                // [{
                //    rental: ...,
                //    device: ...,
                //    last_reading: ...
                //}]

            });

        }
    });
```

### OPTION 2

```
var finalData = [];


//1. I get the client rentals
    Rental.find({
        start_date: {
            "$lte": new Date()
        },
        end_date: {
            "$gte": new Date()
        },
        clientId : ObjectId(req.params.clientId)
    }, 'deviceId', function(err, Rentals)      {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err)
        } else {

            Async.each(Rentals, function(rental, callback) {


                    //2. for reach rental we get In paralel (1 BD query per rental) 
                    Async.parallel([
                        function(callback) {

                                //3.1 Get device by the array of deviceIs (1 BD query per each rental)
                                Device.findOne({
                                    "_id": rental.deviceId
                                },
                                function(err, device) {
                                    if (err) {
                                        callback(err, null);
                                    } else {
                                        callback(null, device)
                                    }
                                }); 

                        },
                        function(callback) {

                                //3.1 Get last reading for each device (one BD query per each rental)
                                Reading.aggregate([
                                    { $match: { "deviceId": rental.deviceId  } },
                                    {
                                        $group: {
                                            deviceId: "$deviceId",
                                            maxCreatedAt: { $max: "$createdAt" }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],function(err, reading) {
                                    if (err) {
                                        callback(err,null);
                                    } else {
                                        callback(null,reading);
                                    }
                                })
                        }
                    ],
                    // optional callback
                    function(err, results) {
                        finalData.push({
                            rental: rental,
                            device: results[0],
                            reading: results[1]
                        });
                    });


            }, function(err) {
                    res.send(finalData);
            });

        }
    });
```

In Option1 I only do 3 DB queries but I need to develop a finalcode to match each rental with its device and its last reading.

In option2 I do far more DB queries but I need no extra code to match each rental.

Which option is better? Is there a better approach?

Comment: To find out which is better, benchmark them both.

Comment: @tadman what's the best way to benchmark both solutions?

Comment: @Paul - Actually, disk activity will usually be the main determinant.  If you have a slow network, then network roundtrips could also be a gating factor, but with a reasonable network, disk activity is probably the bottleneck.  So, it will depend upon which method is more efficient for the database to execute which usually means the fewest queries (and let the DB optimize the ones you have), but the only way to know for sure it so benchmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only answer to which one is faster is to **benchmark and measure**.   We cannot do that for you.  Only you can do that.

If one were to theorize (which is only useful for planning reasonable tests, you still have to do the testing to know), then the components of a database query can be ranked like this (slowest to fastest):

1. Disk access to read data from the database.
2. Network access to communicate with the database server.
3. Local CPU to process the results.

So, your desire is to minimize the slowest operations which means minimizing the times the database has to hit the disk.  Now, that isn't an entirely predictable thing because databases do caching and things like that, but crafting your code into fewer database operations generally gives the database a better chance at optimizing the work (assuming you don't switch to using a really inefficient database operation).

And, minimizing the number of database operations also generally minimizes the network round trips.

So, if there's an efficient way to minimize the number of DB queries as long as you're not doing a really inefficient query or transferring way more data than required, that is usually your first choice.

And, you generally don't need to worry about a little extra CPU on your end to process results of an efficient database query as CPU is generally the fastest link in the chain.

So, the theory says that your option 1 (fewer queries) is more likely to be faster, particularly as data sets get larger.  But, you have to measure.

---

But ... databases can be fast at some things and slow at other things, all depending upon what they can cache, what they have indexed and what they are generally optimized for.  So, **you have to benchmark and measure** to find out what really is fastest.